# Depth-first search (DFS) time complexity for a Red-Black Tree

Tags: binary-search-trees, red-black-trees

If we indicate *n* as the number of nodes of a Red-Black Tree, which is the time complexity of a DFS algorithm that analyzes only the internal nodes of the Tree?

I think that the complexity is O(n), but I'm not sure because of the leaf nodes that the algorithm doesn't need to analyze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of internal nodes in a binary tree is at most $n/2$, which is still $O(n)$, therefore the time it takes to perform a DFS is still $O(n)$.

In the usual implementation of [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), leaves are null nodes. Therefore, only the internal nodes have keys/elements. In this case the number of internal nodes is $n$.

Comment: I agree with you, in the implementation that I have in mind the leaves are null nodes, so they contain nothing.