# Red Black Tree: number of internal nodes vs leaf nodes

Tags: binary-search-trees, red-black-trees

Given a generic Red Black Tree with **n** nodes is correct to say that the number of internal nodes is ⌊n/2⌋ and the number of leaf nodes is ⌊n/2⌋ + 1 ?

Comment: I think the answer to this question has been covered by the answer to your previous question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/150835/118807).

Comment: Just to add, if all nodes are internal then $n$ is the number of internal nodes and there will be $n+1$ null (leaf) nodes.